# How to show context menu with preview?

Tags: ios, swiftui, contextmenu

I was wondering how to show a context menu when holding an element then showing a preview with the menu items in SwiftUI? I know how to show context menu items, but not with the preview and the animation.

View video: https://utilities.awesomeplayer.tech/send/f.php?h=35h_YJr5&p=1

I have tried to attach views inside the Context Menu, before the Buttons, but that has not worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: The following is only available in iOS 16+ and iPadOS 16+. Earlier versions in second part. From the docs:

> This view modifier produces a context menu on macOS, but that platform doesn’t display the preview.

Take a look at the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gridrow/contextmenu(menuitems:preview:). In `iOS` 16+, `contextMenu` accepts a `preview` argument that is `some View`. Example:

```swift
struct myViewWithPreview: View{
var body: some View{
  Text("Hold for contextMenu")
    .contextMenu{
      //ContextMenu stuff here
      //Such as buttons
        Button("Example"){}
   } preview: {//<-- HERE!!!!
      //Here, put any view that you want as a preview. For example, you could put a webview here on a link.
      //You could also do an image, such as how they do it on the docs.
       Text("Preview!")
   }
}
}
```

If you are using earlier OS versions, you must do this using a custom approach. Take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/swiftui-made-easy/context-menu-with-preview-in-swiftui-242eab7b9375). This could also be of use: https://onmyway133.com/posts/how-to-show-context-menu-with-custom-preview-in-swiftui/.